# Very strange GRANT permission issue

Tags: mysql-5.6, users

I am having a very strange issue here with a web app that I have seen working fine in the past.

The server is a simple LAMP stack running MySQL 5.6.30.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

The reason why this issue is causing me problems is because the user `my_user` has all privileges.

Here is the output of the `SHOW GRANTS` query on my MySQL server:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'my_user'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------
| Grants for my_user@localhost                                                                                   
+---------------------------------------------------------------
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '******' 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db1`.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost' 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db2`.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost' 
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db3`.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost'  
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db4`.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost'  
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_db`.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost' 
+---------------------------------------------------------------
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The database called `my_db` is the Database in question for this web app.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should go about diagnosing this issue?

I have confirmed that I am indeed looking at the right server with the correct user and what should be the correct password.

I am also unable to log in to MySQL CLI with this user.

Comment: You may want to mention which action exactly causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Somehow the password for that user got modified/blasted. By resetting the password I have regained access.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the combination of host, user name and password is not allowed to connect to the server, please verify the permission tables (reload grants if required) on the server. You may also restart MySQL service once.